# QGIS Custom CRS Not Saving

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-customization

I'm trying to make a custom CRS by slightly modifying an existing CRS of a basemap I'm using. I wish to shift the basemap slightly to correct for error. Based on what I read I could do this by creating a custom CRS with a modified false easting and northing to offset the basemap to its correct position. I'm good with all this, but every time I try to save my CRS QGIS keeps telling me that the definition of the CRS I'm trying to create is not valid. Even if I keep everything the same from the CRS I'm modifying (i.e., EPSG:3857) and just change the ID, it still won't save. I can't figure out what is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Screen shots of your work flow would help. How are you creating the custom CRS? Please post the WKT of the new CS in text.